# Query to return entities that match two link criterias with Left Outer Join

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a query that should return "A" entities while having links to entity "B" and "C" and these two links have "Left Outer Join" operator so that I can receive "A" entities either from one link or another.

After execution it returns me only one record which is common for two of the link criterias. If I remove link to entity "B" then I get expected records that match the link criteria. Same happens when I remove link to entity "C" while the link to entity "B" is present.

So, I assume that my query works only with one link, but it doesn't work as expected when there are two links and I don't understand why.

Actually I was following this [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531006.aspx).

Here's my data:

```
_____________
|     A     |
-------------
|   a_id    |
|     1     | - entity with this id is the only record in the results
|     2     | - entity with this id should appear in the results, but it is not
|     3     | - entity with this id should appear in the results, but it is not

_________________________________
|               B               |
---------------------------------
|   b_one_id    |   b_two_id    |
|       1       |       1       | - matches link criteria with alias "connectionB"
|       2       |       1       | - matches link criteria with alias "connectionB"
|       1       |       444     | - doesn't match link criteria, should not appear

_________________________________
|               C               |
---------------------------------
|   c_one_id    |   c_two_id    |
|       1       |       2       | - matches link criteria with alias "connectionC"
|       3       |       2       | - matches link criteria with alias "connectionC"
|       1       |       555     | - doesn't match link criteria, should not appear
```

My query expression:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = A.EntityLogicalName,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet
    {
        AllColumns = false,
        Columns =
        {
            "a_id",
            "a_name"
        }
    }
};

query.Distinct = true;

query.AddLink(B.EntityLogicalName, "a_id", "b_one_id", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "connectionB";
query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("b_two_id", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1);

query.AddLink(C.EntityLogicalName, "a_id", "c_one_id", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "connectionC";
query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("c_two_id", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2);

// doesn't work as expected
query.Criteria.AddFilter(LogicalOperator.Or);
query.Criteria.Filters[0].AddCondition("connectionB", "b_one_id", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
query.Criteria.Filters[0].AddCondition("connectionC", "c_one_id", ConditionOperator.NotNull);

// doesn't work as expected either
query.Criteria.AddCondition("a_id", ConditionOperator.NotNull);
```

The query expression gets transformed into following Fetch XML query:

```
<fetch distinct="true" no-lock="false" mapping="logical">
    <entity name="A">
        <attribute name="a_id" />
        <attribute name="a_name" />
        <filter type="and">
            <filter type="or">
                <!-- doesn't work as expected -->
                <condition attribute="b_one_id" operator="not-null" entityname="connectionB" />
                <condition attribute="c_one_id" operator="not-null" entityname="connectionC" />

                <!-- doesn't work as expected either -->
                <condition attribute="a_id" operator="not-null" entityname="A" />
            </filter>
        </filter>
        <link-entity name="B" to="a_id" from="b_one_id" link-type="outer" alias="connectionB">
            <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="b_two_id" operator="eq" value="1" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
        <link-entity name="C" to="a_id" from="c_one_id" link-type="outer" alias="connectionC">
            <filter type="and">
                <condition attribute="c_two_id" operator="eq" value="2" />
            </filter>
        </link-entity>
    </entity>
</fetch>
```

Comment: Just tried it and works fine for me - got 3 rows. Can you try to run without any filters and see if data you are running against is correct (i get 6 rows without filters: 4 rows where a_id=1,  1 where  a_id=2, 1 where a_id=3)?

Comment: Hello, is this crm 2011 or crm 2013? Wich rollup?
If this is crm 2011 `outer join` works in this way:
If you link a relasionship with `outer` you are going to retrieve `ALL records`, even if they dont match your condition.

Answer (score 0):

I hope There is some programming mistake in Your Code.
Look at Your Code Part

```
query.AddLink(B.EntityLogicalName, "a_id", "b_one_id", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "connectionB";
query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("b_two_id", ConditionOperator.Equal, 1);

query.AddLink(C.EntityLogicalName, "a_id", "c_one_id", JoinOperator.LeftOuter);
query.LinkEntities[0].EntityAlias = "connectionC";
query.LinkEntities[0].LinkCriteria.AddCondition("c_two_id", ConditionOperator.Equal, 2);
```

You are adding query.AddLink() and again Adding some other Link to query 
but Using the same Link ie query.LinkEntities[0] for Alias and LinkCriteria.
May be correcting this mistake can solve your Problem.